# Kotlin- Is there any way to update a single field in collection item in Kotlin without foreach?

Tags: kotlin, foreach

I am working on `Android` application using `kotlin`. I am pretty much new to kotlin and I have the following scenario.

I have the list of users in a List collection object with the fields such as `firstName` , `lastName`, `mobile` and `hasDeleted`

```
var myList: List<Users>
myList = <I have list of users here>
```

I would like to update only one flag `hasDeleted` with the value `true` for each Users.

I understand that we can use `foreach` to update the value. But, I would like to know if any other approach I can follow.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing with current approach ? Are you not able to update the data class value ?

Comment: @Rakesh, There is no specific method in the kotlin to update a field of all items present in the list and you have to iterate through all the items and update the value.

Comment: A traditional for loop is preferred for readability when you aren’t chaining functional calls, but either that or forEach is the best, most consider way to do this.

Comment: Because each `User` has their own `hasDeleted`, you will need to visit all the `User`s you want to modify. You can do this with foreach, map or for loop, but you will need to visit all of them.

Comment: As Karunesh says: _why_ do you want to avoid `forEach()`? Looking for an alternative to iteration isn't a bad idea, since Kotlin often has better approaches — but in this case that's probably the best. Do you have a specific reason for not using that?

Answer (score 4):

The only reason for not using `forEach` is if your `Users` object is immutable (which you should at least consider) and it is a data class defined as follows:

```kotlin
data class Users(val firstName: String, 
                 val lastName: String, 
                 val mobile: String, 
                 val hasDeleted: Boolean)
```

If this is what you have, then `map` is your best option, since you can no longer change a `Users` object with `hasDeleted = true` because they are not mutable. In this case, you should use the following which will return a list with the updated `Users` objects.

```kotlin
myList.map { it.copy(hasDeleted = true) }
```

Other than this specific case, I see no good reason to avoid using `forEach`.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use map for it:

```
myList.map { it.hasDeleted = true }
```

it will update all `hasDeleted` as `true` in the list.

Comment: This will work, but it will do exactly the same as foreach. Also `map` returns a new collection so the intention of your code is going to be confusing to anybody reading it

Comment: This does the same thing as `forEach` except it also will waste cycles and memory creating a List of Units.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can do it with the following approach

```
var myList: List<User>
myList.map { it.hasDeleted = true}
```

The map will replace the value of hasDeleted for all the list items to true/false, whatever you will provide.

Here is a tested sample with expected results.

[image]

Comment: No, it will only update the first item that meets the condition, and it will throw an exception if none of them meet the condition. The correct way to do what you’re describing is to use `filter` and then `forEach`, but that’s not what the question is about anyway.

Comment: Yes! @Tenfour04 you are right. It was my mistake. We should use "list.map{it. hasDeleted=true}" to achieve the above results.

Comment: Well, you shouldn’t use `map` either. See the comments on the other answer that was suggesting that.